# Creating a site wide template for React apps

Tags: html, css, reactjs

New to React and wanted to get some insight on how best to create a website that will eventually have many SPAs, developed by different teams.

Ideally, a team would want to create a new SPA, and they would be able to add some stuff to their SPA that would allow for their site to share a common look/feel and perhaps navigation as well.

I am envisioning this where there is a master navigation (header, nav menu, etc) which I control, and many of these link into sub-pages that are actually stand alone SPA pages. But if we want to share things like settings, permissions, layout scheme, is there a tried and true way of doing this?

I am a veteran web developer who is really new to the Angular or React ways. In the day I would just create a frame, or, have a header that was a server-side include of sorts. But I feel as though things might be very different or more sophisticated now.

The goal here would be if we wanted to change the look/feel scheme, or wanted to change the master header/nav, we wouldn't have to update all of the SPAs individually to do that. So this is more than how to create a SPA (which is very well documented), but more of a "as a firm what can we do to centralize and house all of our team's web apps?"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you aware of server-side rendering ? (next.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look into "Higher Order Components (HOCs)" in React. Basically, you will define a Layout inside a React Component (let's say you create `/src/components/Layout/Layout.js`), there you import your `Header(.js)` and `Footer(.js)` components and put `{props.children}` in the middle (this is where content of routes gets rendered.

But before you can do that, you should learn how routing, nesting components, props and stuff work, or else what I wrote may not make much sense.